# Org mode: how to set a deadline to an already appointed meeting date

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

I'm kinda new to org-mode and I was wondering whether it is possible to set a deadline for a `TODO` task to a meeting date? I try to be more specific in the following:

I have a meeting org file within which I keep all my meetings dates under headlines (ie. no `SCHEDULED` nor `DEADLINE`): *appointments.org* :

```
* Meeting with boss <2021-01-25>
* Meeting with John <2021-02-03>
```

What I would like when associating a `DEADLINE` date to a `TODO` in another *org* file, is to interactively select a specific meeting that my task corresponds to in my *appointments.org* (in that case 'Meeting with boss'). This way, the date of the `TODO` `DEADLINE` could be dynamically linked to that of the meeting: should the meeting's date change, the `TODO` `DEADLINE` would also shift:

```
* Tasks
** TODO Do something for boss 
DEADLINE: <????-??-??> <-- select "* Meeting with boss" within appointments.org
** Other Task
```

So far nothing like this showed up in my researches, at least no "build-in" features.

Thanks for any feedback on this!

Comment: How do you link the `TODO` entry in one file with an appointment entry in a different file?

Comment: well I guess I could use the agenda: [C-c a] would allow me to find a meeting date within appointments.org? If not suitable, the question can be asked if the meeting date is within the same org file as the TODO. Would the answer be easier in that case?

Comment: No, whether they are in the same file or in another file does not make much difference - you need to tell us how you intend to tie the two items together.

Comment: Well, this is ~ the point of my question… Supposing my meetings are stored/organised by headlines (one headline = one meeting title & a calendar date), could I set a TODO DEADLINE date to that of a specific headline? Sorry again, I'm new to this.

Comment: I clarified my question, thanks @NickD